# How can I have conditional out parameters

Tags: c#

The method `DoSomething()` does Create an Instance of `MyClass` but not everyone wants to know the `MyClass-Object` sometimes it also fits if you simply know if the action was successful.

#### This doesn't compile

```
public bool DoSomething(out Myclass myclass = null)
{
    // Do something
}
```

> A ref or out parameter cannot have a default value

Sure I could simply remove the `out-Keyword` but then I needed to assign any variable first, which is not my intention.

#### This could be a workaround, but i want bool to be the return type

```
public Myclass DoSomething() //returns null if not successful
{
    // Do something
}
```

*Does anyone know a nice Workaround for that?*

Comment: Just create another overload `bool DoSomething()`.

Comment: @Dirk this would be nice workaround you're my hero.. (For real not sarcastic, i've really missed that) BUT omitted for clarity there are several optional parameters I am already using as input for `DoSomething()` that's why it is not my requested workaround. It needs to be done all in the same Method-Declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap the parameter in a class.

```
class Arguments
{
public Argument () { Arg = null; }
public Myclass Arg { get; set; }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
Arguments args;
if (DoSomething (args))
{
  // args.Arg is something
}
```

and define the function like:

```
bool DoSomething (Arguments args)
{
  bool success = false;
  if (someaction)
  {
    args.Arg = new Myclass;
    success = true;
  }
  return success;
}
```

Alternative, and this is making me feel a bit dirty, use exceptions:-

```
Myclass DoSomething ()
{
  if (someactionhasfailed)
  {
    throw new Exception ("Help");
  }
  return new Myclass;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. Not looking at the *feel a bit dirty part* makes this the answer fitting best to me.

Comment: "Exceptions as flow control" now there's a can of worms!

Answer (score 8):

Just by overloading:

```
public bool DoSomething()
{
    myClass i;
    return DoSomething(out i);
}

public bool DoSomething(out myClass myclass)
{
    myclass = whatever;
    return true;
}
```

And then call `DoSomething()`

Comment: The only problem here, as far as I understand it, is that 'i' isn't returned to the caller of 'DoSomething'. EDIT: Rereading the question this does seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @Skizz in fact, the more I read the OP's question, the less I'm sure I understood it right :/

Comment: Let's hope he never writes a spec for someone then!

Comment: @Skizz What do you do if you're the one who needs to follow the spec ;)

Comment: @LuckyLikey: Enter an infinitely recursive loop?

Comment: @skizz and using exceptions to leave it? Youd be my favourite developer :))

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to overload the method, you can always create a new class like:

```
public class Response
    {
    public bool Success{get;set;}
    public Myclass MyclassInstance {get;set;}
    }
```

And the use it as a return parameter of your DoSomething() method with the following signature:

```
public Response DoSomething() 
{
    // Do something
}
```